# Drawing a 3D cone shape in Swift using a UIBezierPath() and CAShapeLayer()

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, drawing, uibezierpath

**Background**

I’m attempting to draw a 3D cone shape as shown in the image below.

I have a method that I use to draw a simple triangle and fill it with a solid color in Swift using a `UIBezierPath()` and `CAShapeLayer()`.

---

**Question**

In Swift code, how can I draw a 3D cone shape or fill the triangle
shape I’ve drawn with a complex gradient that gives the triangle shape
a 3D effect and effectively a cone appearance?

---

**Code**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
        path.closePath()

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path.CGPath
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

        myView.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

---

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would draw the gradient in a rectangle, generate a bitmap, then use a 2d or 3d transform. I tested that it might look right doing it in photoshop just now, and it looks pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was something that could be generated by code that was close to a fill for example `shape.fillColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor`.

Comment: My guess is that the builtin gradient methods take a vector and draw along it only. The other option would be to write your own fill method, in this instance it draws lines form the top point to each point on the bottom changing the color each time (well, dont know if that will work out of hand, but thats the gist). 3rd option would be to just light and render a cone =)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with light and render a cone, but that's an interesting approach of writing a custom fill method, I might investigate it further. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve your goal making use of `CGGradientLayer` with a type of `conic`. The trick is to use the triangle shape as a mask for the gradient.

Here is an example that can be run in a Swift Playground. Comments in the code.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ConeView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Just for display
        backgroundColor = .yellow

        // Create the triangle to be used as the gradient's mask
        // Base the size of the triangle on the view's frame
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: 0))
        path.close()

        // Create a shape from the path
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path.cgPath

        // Create a conical gradient and mask it with the triangle shape
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: -0.5)
        gradientLayer.type = .conic
        // Change the white value of the center color to adjust the center highlight brightness as desired
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        // Tweak the 1st and 3rd number as desired.
        // The closer to 0.5 the darker the cone edges will be.
        // The further from 0.5 the lighter the cone edges will be.
        gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.38, 0.5, 0.62 ]
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.mask = shape
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// Set whatever size you want for the view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ConeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
```

Here's the result (the black border is not part of the view, just part of the screen capture):

[image]

Comment: Note that the `conic` gradient type was added in iOS 12 (2018) and wasn't available when the question was originally posted back in 2017.

Comment: Thank you. Was there a way to do this without `conic` gradient type?

Comment: @user4806509 I would think you would have to emulate the conic gradient yourself by drawing lines of varying shades of gray at appropriate angles from the apex of the triangle. I see no reason unless you have some reason to still support iOS 11.